# Python Date Time with JSON API

Tags: python, json, django, date, time

I have a Python 2.7 API that queries a SQL db and delivers a JSON list of dictionaries that is then used in a bootstrap/Django site.

Dates in the DB are strings in the format `'2017-04-20 00:00:00'`, but sometimes the time of the source data instead has a decimal, which causes trouble with `strptime`, so I'm removing the seconds by keeping only the first 10 characters of the string.

```
import datetime

dict_list = response['my_list_of_dicts']
for dt_to_cmpr in dict_list:
    dt_to_cmpr['date_key'] = dt_to_cmpr['date_key'][:10]
```

Before I can compare date ranges, the dates need to be date time not strings. (Note: For production, I plan to account for exceptions such as null values.)

```
    dt_to_cmpr['date_key'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_to_cmpr['date_key'], 
        '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I want to know things about dictionaries where `date_key` is roughly no more than 90 days from today. (i.e. the total number in the time frame, or the sum of every dictionary's price_key.)

```
under_days = datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
over_days = datetime.timedelta(days=91)
now = datetime.datetime.now()

ttl_within_90days = sum(1 for d in response['my_list_of_dicts'] if (under_days <
    (d.get('date_key')-now) < over_days))
```

One problem is now that I've converted my dates, the are not `JSON serializable`. So, now I have to put them back into a string again

```
for dt_to_cmpr in dict_list:
    dt_to_cmpr['date_key'] = dt_to_cmpr['date_key'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

I cleaned up the above for simplicity, but that should all work. When it gets to Django, the view is going to covert them all back to date time again for use in a template.

Can I have Python just treat my date strings as time for the 90 day comparison, but leave them alone. Or, maybe have JSON use the Python date times? That much iteration every page load is slow, and can't be the best way.

Comment: Why do you have to serialize your datetimes to json to pass to Django, why can't you just pass it the regular python datetimes?  What database are you using?  Most databases support native datetime fields.  Is your *api* separate from django?

Comment: Yes. It is a completely separate API. The only reason I mention Django, is that it is just one more piece adding additional time.

Comment: Is there any reason why your api has to return date strings?  Do you control the database?  Can you just change the database to store actual datetime values?

Comment: I don't control the database. Within a year, I'd like to have all the data in my own db, but for now it's elsewhere. I can ask them to change though.

Comment: I could consider pulling all the calcs out of the API, and handling everything directly in the Django view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the way you're storing the datetimes.  You should probably be storing them *as actual datetimes* in your database, not strings.  You can't do date queries on string fields.  Instead, you have to use the inefficient method  of querying *all the records* and then filtering all of them in python after the fact.  Database data types were created for a reason, use them.

There's no reason to convert datetimes to strings except at the very last moment when you need to format it for json or html, and the only bit of code that should need to do that is the Django app.  That means:

- Your Django app should almost entirely be using datetimes.  It only coverts to strings when it needs to render out html or json.
- Your API should only use python datetimes.
- Your database should only use datetimes as well.

If you don't control the database, the best case is going to be 2 conversions

1. `string -> datetime` when pulling data out of the database.
2. `datetime -> string` when serializing to html or json.

If you can fix the database, then you only need to do the 2nd conversion.